# Entity Framework: 'x' does not contain a definition for 'y' and no extension method 'y' accepting a first argument of type 'x' could be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I read the other questions that had the same error, but they don't seem to deal with Entity Framework. Unfortunately I'm not experienced with EF, so I'm reaching out to the community for help. Can someone please give me an idea how to eliminate this error?

Thanks.

Sorry for not including the code. I'll post whatever is necessary to help me figure this out:

```
private int MarkPreviousCallsUncallable(DAL.Dialer.I3_IC_DIALEREntities context, 
    string lob, DataRowCollection i3Identities)
{
    <presumably unrelated stuff>

    var existingDIYContact = context.DIYOUTBOUNDPREVIEW.Where
        (x => x.I3_IDENTITY == i3Identity).FirstOrDefault();

    <presumably unrelated stuff>
}
```

It's on the `var existingDIYContact` line where I'm getting the error.

Comment: You need to give us SOMETHING to work with. Right now, we have zero clue as to any reason why that error might be occurring. You need to show some code.

Comment: Sharing some code would help us to track down the problem

Comment: I highly doubt this is related to EF. It looks like you're calling a method that either doesn't exist or an extension whose namespace hasn't been included.

Comment: Sorry for not including the code. I'll gladly post anything I need to...

Comment: Post the region where the error is occurring.

Comment: Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file?

Comment: You can pass the predicate that you are currently passing to `Where` directly to `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: What is `y` here? Are you sure that `I3_IDENTITY` is the propertyname in x? what is the type of x? can you post the code for that type?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

Actually there were two problems. One is that my model was pointing to the wrong database, and the other problem was that even though the table name is DIYOUTBOUNDPREVIEW, for some reason I had to pluralize it in my call:

```
var existingDIYContact = context.DIYOUTBOUNDPREVIEWs.Where(x => x.I3_IDENTITY == i3Identity).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks all for your help.